# How to append an exception's StackTrace into a file in java?

Tags: java, exception, printstream

In java, when we catch a exception, we usually can use `printStackTrace()` method to print the error information, and we can also use `printStackTrace(PrintStream out)` to direct those information to a file.

But how can I append those information into a existing file, just like using `out.append()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must open file in append mode:

```
try {
    //...
} catch (Exception e) {
    try(Writer w = new FileWriter("file.log", true)) {
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(w)));
    }
}
```

If you are not using Java 7, you must remember about closing or at least flushing the `Writer`. Or you can have a global `Writer`, but then you must synchronize it between threads.

What about simply using some existing Java library like [logback](/questions/tagged/logback), [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j) or even `java.util.logging`? Simply say:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Opps!", e);
}
```

...and the framework will log the exception wherever you want, with lots of additional data like thread name, timestamp, additional message, etc. Logback can also show you from which library given stack frame comes from and even print the stack trace starting from root cause (most nested exception).

Comment: Why do you need the BufferedWriter and not new PrintWriter(w)?

Answer (score 5):

We can redirect the error stream to a file

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("errors.txt", true), true));
```

then Throwable.printStackTrace() will print to errors.txt.

"true" in FileOutputStream constructor means "append"; "true" in PrintStream condtructor means "autoflush". We do not need to worry about never closing FileOutputStream, OS will close it when the app ends.